# How to sort site.posts alphabetically by post.title in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I have some `.md` posts, like:

- 2016-10-01-first_post.md (title: FIRST)
- 2016-10-03-some_post.md (title: SOME)
- 2016-10-04-another_post.md (title: ANOTHER)
- 2016-10-07-my_post.md (title: MY)
- 2016-10-08-just_a_post.md (title: JUST)

and I created a `.html` file:

```
---
layout: default
title: Archives
---
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
<li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

then I got a posts list sorted by file names:

```
• FIRST
• SOME
• ANOTHER
• MY
• JUST
```

I want to sort the posts in `site.posts` alphabetically by `post.title`, but I don't know how:

```
• ANOTHER
• FIRST
• JUST
• MY
• SOME
```

So I'm looking for some help, thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use sort filter like this : `{% assign sortedPosts = site.posts | sort: 'title' %}` and then loop over `sortedPosts` with:

```
{% for post in sortedPosts %}
  <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that you cannot do `{% for post in sortedPosts | sort: 'title' %}`. You must assign and then loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a variable to the site.posts array and sort them using | sort: post.title. Source: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#sort

Then loop through the array, just like you normally would through the posts.

Comment: It looks like that syntax might be obsolete. Only `sort: 'title'` worked for me.

Comment: but 5+ years ago...

Comment: Sure, just making people aware of it.